# Is dependency analysis required in order to type a program?

Tags: functional-programming, typing, type-inference

I have seen stated in various places that in order to allow an "increase in polymorphism," functional dependency analysis should be performed, and type inference should be used for every declaration group in topological order. It seems like a well-known fact... except that nobody provides any reference or example.

In fact I don't understand what is really meant by this statement. Does it mean that without doing dependency analysis I wouldn't be able to type some programs (i.e. some valid programs would fail type-checking) or only that I would type them with a type that is more specific than what really is?

I'm particularly interested in consequences in a Haskell-like language/type system. In particular during *kind inference*, is dependency analysis actually necessary to avoid rejecting valid programs? Can you provide an example that wouldn't be well-kinded if typed without performing dependency analysis?

Since kinds are monomorphic I struggle to understand why dependency analysis should matter in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any use of a type anywhere may place constraints on that type. So, in the absence of explicit type signatures (i.e. when doing type *inference*) it is necessary to perform inference in a way that doesn't allow *specific* usages of a type in a particular form to "infect" the most general type it may have. This involves a dependency analysis. Consider

```
id = \x -> x
foo = id 1
```

Now if we type foo first, we would unify the first argument of `id` with `Int` and thus conclude `id` had type `Int -> Int`. So therefore we must first type `id` and then *generalize* its signature to the polymorphic type `forall a. a -> a`, and *then* instantiate that at type `Int` when we apply it and attempt to unify the argument type with `Int`.

Hence, dependencies and topological sort!

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the second part of my question. What if the language is *not* polymorphic (e.g. the kinds in Haskell 98). Does *not* using dependency analysis "kind" incorrectly some programs or not "kind" at all some well-kinded programs?

Comment: @Bakuriu The Haskell report gives an example where the choice of what dependencies to include in kind analysis makes a difference http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#kindinference